# Named Pipe server can't get the pipe handle state

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I'm currently working on an application that acts as the server for a named pipe. This application is solely designed to send data out to a client (not written by me), but also needs to be informed of when the pipe is broken. My idea for this task was to use `GetNamedPipeHandleState()` to retrieve the number of instances of the pipe and see if the pipe was still resident in the system. If it was no longer connected, the program is designed to reset the pipe so that the client can reconnect and resume pulling data from the application. Unfortunately, I can't retrieve the number of instances of the pipe. Whenever the call is made, the function fails with `GetLastError()` returning `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. However, this only occurs if I attempt the call as follows:

```
GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(pipe,0,&npipeinstances,0,0,0,0);
```

If I call the function like this:

```
GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(pipe,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

no errors occur, but I don't receive any state information. Is there a creation parameter that could be missing, or a better way to check for this information?

The creation code for the pipe is as follows:

```
pipe=CreateNamedPipeA(pipename,             // name of the pipe
                      PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, // read/write access 
                      PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |   // message type pipe 
                      PIPE_WAIT,            // blocking mode 
                      1,                    // max. instances  
                      65535,                // output buffer size 
                      65535,                // input buffer size 
                      300,                  // client time-out 
                      NULL);                // default security attribute
```

Comment: Well, if you call it with ALL parameters [except the handle] zero, it probably skips the check that gives you ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when you call with `&npipeinstances`.

Comment: @Mats That still leaves the main problem of how to fix the issue. I could probably hack it by checking the return of WriteFile, but I need the check to be done even when there is no data to write (which skips the WriteFile call). This seems to be the best way to do the check, unless I've missed something in the API.

Comment: This is just the wrong way to go about it.  A broken pipe is a major mishap, the odds that you can "reconnect" to the same client instance are zilch.  You find out it when the ReadFile() call fails.  You should always have one pending so you can quickly respond to client sends.  So no need to poll separately.

Comment: That may be the case, but the pipe is being created with write access only. A ReadFile wouldn't work anyway on that pipe. In regards to a reconnect, when the pipe connection is lost, the pipe is closed down on the server end and opened with the same name, almost as if the process starts over. If the client reconnects, it will either find that the pipe doesn't exist, in which case it can wait and retry, or that it does, and the pipe is reestablished. This is the behavior requested by the user, also, so there's no real way to change it.

Comment: This question is slightly related to a [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378615/how-to-verify-an-outbound-only-server-end-pipe-handle-is-a-pipe).

Answer (score 1):

From the [API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365443%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> hNamedPipe [in] A handle to the named pipe for which information is
>   wanted. The handle must have GENERIC_READ access for a read-only or
>   read/write pipe, or it must have GENERIC_WRITE and
>   FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES access for a write-only pipe.

If you have opened your pipe handle (`pipe`) with only `PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND`, I don't think you satisfy this condition. Hence the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` error.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Client ends of inbound-(to-server-)only pipes can be opened using `GENERIC_WRITE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`, and then `GetNamedPipeInfo` works fine, but I haven't found any way to get the same access set for the server end of an outbound-only pipe. Ridiculous!