# How to verify an outbound-only server-end pipe handle is a pipe?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I want to create an outbound-only named pipe, and I want other code elsewhere to later be able to check if that handle is a pipe. This works for all cases of pipe handles (client, server; outbound, inbound), EXCEPT server-end handles to outbound-only pipes.

If I open a handle to the client end of an inbound-to-server-only pipe with access flags `GENERIC_WRITE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`, I can later verify the handle is a pipe by calling `GetNamedPipeInfo(handle,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)`, which returns true. However, the server end lacks this privilege for outbound-only pipes — if I call `CreateNamedPipe` with `PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND`, `GetNamedPipeInfo` returns false and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: your question is unclear. all what you open on pipe device is pipe by definition

Comment: Given a handle, how do I reliably verify it is a pipe?

Comment: from where you have handle ? and what is your final target ?

Comment: @RbMm, I am looking for a general answer to this question, which makes no assumptions about where the handle comes from. (Final usage of the handle is irrelevant.) Obviously, in the absence of a general solution, and where I have extra pieces of info like those, I can hack around this problem. So, workaround-type answers to this question are unhelpful for me.

Comment: the end goal is always important and from where handle comes. safe way call `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` with `FileFsDeviceInformation` and compare `DeviceType` with `FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE` but formal this is not 100% mean pipe. your code - can hung if pipe open in synchronous mode and have not completed i/o

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. I’m trying to avoid calling Nt functions, and stick to WinAPI, though, because Nt is officially undocumented and so I can’t trust it’ll behave the same way two versions of Windows in the future.

Comment: [`NtQueryVolumeInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvolumeinformationfile) is **officially documented** and 100% trust - was, exist and will be always

Comment: The doc for `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` says the handle must have been opened with `NtCreateFile` or `NtOpenFile`, neither of which I can assume was used in my use-case.

Comment: you again wrong assume.

Comment: at first documentation is **wrong** - no play any role with which api call created file handle - this can be any valid file handle. for example created with `ZwCreateNamedPipeFile` or `ZwCreateMailslotFile`. or say `IoCreateFile`. at second *neither of which I can assume was used in my use-case* - and what you think used in your case ? this not play any role, just interesting

Comment: In my use case, all of the pipe handles will have been created by `CreateNamedPipe`, `CreatePipe`, and `CreateFile`.

Comment: and internal this api call call `NtCreateNamedPipeFile` , and `NtCreateFile`. but main - **documentation is wrong** - very bad written

Comment: @rbm: The documentation is correct. It's the official contract. A conforming implementation is entitled to loosen its preconditions. Which is what you are apparently observing. That doesn't invalidate the documented contract.

Comment: @IInspectable - documentation is **wrong**. and this is was many time. this is not contract, but bad written. the api accept handle to a **file object**. which api used for create this handle **not play any role**. even more - this impossible detect. anyway all this api have common point `IoCreateFile[Ex]` - look like you dont know this

Comment: @rbm: If you are *this* confident, that the documentation is wrong, why don't you [fix](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs-ddi/blob/staging/wdk-ddi-src/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvolumeinformationfile.md) it?

Comment: @IInspectable may be know, but if no - read about [`ObReferenceObjectByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle) which always called for convert handle to corresponding pointer to the object's body. and in this case `IoFileObjectType` used. are `CreateFile` or `NtCreateFile` or `NtCreateNamedPipeFile` used as initial point at all undetectable - all it lead to `IoCreateFile`

Comment: @IInspectable - i not write documentation and not fix it. this is not my job. i simply say here what know any windows kernel developer

Comment: @rbm: I'm sure you can pull all that information into the comment for your pull request. The kernel folks will happily merge it. *If* they agree. Now be prepared that they will just reject it.

Comment: @IInspectable - what you try to say ? that `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` not accept file handle created say by `NtCreateNamedPipeFile` ? by `IoCreateFile` ? :)

Comment: @rbm: I'm saying that if you feel the documentation is wrong you need to fix it. If you don't fix it, because it's *"not your job"* (dude, you don't even have a job), you'll have to continue to defend your misguided view.

Comment: @IInspectable what you try to say ? that NtQueryVolumeInformationFile not accept file handle created say by `NtCreateNamedPipeFile` ? by `IoCreateFile` ? :)

Comment: I'm not *trying* to say anything. I *am* saying, that the documentation lays out the contract. The contract is clear. To anyone who understands, what a contract is.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
bool IsPipe(HANDLE maybePipe)
{
#if 1
    ULONG junk;
    return
        //This returns a false negative for server-side pipe endpoints opened as PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND.
        //I tried or-ing that with FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, but CreateNamedPipe doesn't like that.
        ::GetNamedPipeInfo(maybePipe, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)
            //So we fall back onto this one, which returns true in that case,
            // and false for non-pipes.
            || ::GetNamedPipeServerSessionId(maybePipe, &junk);
#elif 0
    return
        //THIS RETURNS TRUE FOR NON-PIPE FILES X-(
        ::GetNamedPipeHandleState(maybePipe, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
#endif
}
```

Comment: this is not solution at all. for example what granted access have your handle ? without this knowledge you can not call this api. what is file opened for synchronous i/o and exist active i/o request (usually read) - you agree hung here ?

Comment: - Fortunately, as I have verified, this works regardless of the access mode of the handle.

Comment: - Checking the error code is unnecessary here for my purposes. It is sufficient to check returned bools. Folks who want those extra checks can feel free to add them.

Comment: *this works* no, this is wrong. you nothing verified. *Checking the error code is unnecessary* - also wrong.